# CALCULATING RECORDS IN VB2010

Tags: sql, vb.net

Below mention code I used in Visual Basic 6 to get Total Salary. Now I want to know how to use the same code in VISUAL BASIC 2010 and my Table in SQL Server.

SQL Code in VB6.

```
 With recordsetEmployee
        .MoveFirst
        TotSalary = .Fields("TotSalary")
    Do While .EOF = False
    TotSalary = TotSalary + .Fields("BasicSalary") + .Fields("OT") - .Fields("Loan")
      .Fields("TotSalary") = TotSalary
      .MoveNext
    Loop
 End With
```

or give me some sample codes how use above code like DO WHILE .EOF Then with that LOOP codes. Better show me handling these command with DATASET OR TABLEBINDINGSOURCE ....please instruct.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`SqlDataReader` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx).
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is a tutorial.

Comment: Please can u use the same my Table Fields into your sample and get me Total Salary, actually I need a calculation in my Table to get total only this way. or pls show me how make code with Tablebindingsource and MOVE FIRST, DO WHILE .EOF with sql code... any samples.

Comment: I will not write your program for you.  You need to read the documentation for `SqlDataReader` and learn how to use it.

Answer (score -1):

VB 2006 and 2010 are very similar. I think all that needs to change is 
A. Take out the periods (ex. .Fields)
B. You do not need (=TotSalary) at the end of your loop in VB 2010